# Flyway 5.0.7 not working with cockroach db V. 2.0

Tags: java, flyway, cockroachdb

This is my scenario.

- **Cockroach DB Verions = 2.0**
- **Flyway Ceriosn = 5.0.7**
- **Platform = Docker**

I have a java app that uses flyway to manage my schemas.

My configuration look like below:
my flyway build.gradle looks like:

```
buildscript {
dependencies {
    classpath "org.postgresql:postgresql:42.1.4"
 }
}
 plugins {
     id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "5.0.7"
 }

description = "test-app"

flyway {
    url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/test_dev?sslmode=disable
 user = root
password = 
}
```

Im running cockroach v 2.0 in insecure mode on my localhost.

When i run:

```
gradle flywayClean
```

i get

```
Flyway upgrade recommended: CockroachDB 2.0 is newer than this version of Flyway and support 
has not been tested.
Unable to clean unknown schema: "test_dev"
```

When i run:

```
gradle flywayMigrate
```

i get:

```
Database: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:26257/test_dev (PostgreSQL 9.5)
Flyway upgrade recommended: CockroachDB 2.0 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...
Creating schema "test_dev" ...

:test-migrations:flywayMigrate (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 19.995 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test-migrations:flywayMigrate'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate

  Unable to create schema "test_dev"
  --------------------------------------------------
  SQL State  : 42P04
  Error Code : 0
  Message    : ERROR: database "test_dev" already exists

  ERROR: database "test_dev" already exists
```

What could i be missing here?

Comment: Support for cockroach has been pushed and merged to master. If you build from source you can already have it, or you can wait for the 5.1 release: https://github.com/flyway/flyway/commit/f8426e24209a1ff1f06def9baffbd088dee1e532

Answer (score 1):

According the documentation, only the version 1.1 is supported.

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/cockroachdb

Version 2.0 will be supported with the Flyway 5.1 release.

https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1970

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem, so I built it for those with the same problem. Use this until the 5.1 release, here's a snippet from an example gradle file.

```
buildscript {
//...
  repositories {
    //...
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    //...
  }
//..
}

plugins {
  //...
  id "com.radioafricagroup.plugins.flyway" version "0.6.7"
  //...
}
```

Also here's a medium post explaining how and why I did this if interested: https://medium.com/radio-africa-techblog/adventures-with-gradle-getting-flyway-to-work-with-cockroachdb-69aabf58cbd4